# Failed dependency on libstdc++(GLIBCXX_...) when installing RPM

Tags: c++, gcc, rpm

I have a linux box on which I've compiled and installed a newer version of GCC (4.3.9), which is present in /usr/lib.

I used this compiler to build a set of libraries which I have bundled into an RPM, but when I come to try install that RPM it gives the the following errors:

```
rpm -ivh my-rpm.i586.rpm  
error: Failed dependencies:  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.10) is needed by my-rpm.i586  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by my-rpm.i586  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) is needed by my-rpm.i586  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20) is needed by my-rpm.i586  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) is needed by my-rpm.i586
```

I know that these symbols are provided by the gcc I compiled:

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX  
...  
GLIBCXX_3.4.10  
GLIBCXX_3.4.11  
...   
GLIBCXX_3.4.15  
...   
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
```

And if I do ldd on any of the .so files packaged into the RPM I can see that it is expecting the correct libstdc++:

```
ldd BUILDROOT/usr/lib/libfoo.so  
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7635000)
```

So I think my only issue is getting RPM's dependency resolver to look in the right place. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567865/how-to-point-to-the-newer-version-of-gcc-libs-when-installing-rpms) implies LD_LIBRARY_PATH is what determines that search path, but setting this in my .bashrc doesn't seem to have helped (and I can see it is set with echo in the same shell I am running rpm -i from).

What variables do I need to set (and where) to get the RPM installer to understand where my libstdc++ is?

Comment: rpm checks for the dependencies in the `provides` of other rpms and not in what is installed in your path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `rpm` works with "metadata". The official libstdc++6 package *provides*:

```
...
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.10)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)
...
```

rpm won't start investigating the installed /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 to see if it provides `GLIBCXX_3.4.10`. Afaik there is no way to tell rpm to do so. I see multiple ways to solve this problem; in order of my preference:

1. **rebuild** the libstdc++ 4.3.9 rpm yourself and install it; then all the dependencies will work out fine (you can look [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3) to find gcc*src.rpm). As for me; that is the only future-proof solution!
2. when packaging my-rpm; use the option [`AutoReqProv: no`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html); to tell `rpm` not to scan automatically for his requirements. Of course then you might run into dependency problems; where you'll have to determine and install the dependencies manually.
3. when installing my-rpm; use the option `--nodeps` to ignore the dependencies. This might cause trouble with other dependencies (because now *all* dependencies will be ignored).

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I will start with trying suggestion #1 then

Comment: once you start doing that it is really easy: get src.rpm; run `rpmbuild --rebuild your.src.rpm` and install the resulting rpms...